# Javascript how to stop setTimeOut

Tags: javascript, settimeout, smooth-scrolling

Hellow 
I ran into a little problem i don't know how to stop my add function when it reaches some Y position on my web, can some body help me whit it!!

```js
var scroll = function(){
 
 var positionYTop = 0,

  speed = 50,
  links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

 function timer() {
  var clock = setTimeout(add, 200)
 }

 function add() {
  window.scrollTo(0, positionYTop += speed);
  timer();
 }

 add();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common approach to this is to start off by setting the scroll in advance, along with a transform/translateY in the other direction to offset the effect of the scroll, then transition the transform down to zero.

Basically, in this day and age, we want the browser/CSS to do the transition. It's less code, and using transform it will be much smoother.

Here's a very rough idea (not tested, you will need to play with it):

```
body.start {
  transform: translateY(-400px);
}

body.transitioned {
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: transform 1s;
}

function scroll() {
  document.body.scrollTop; = 400;
  document.body.classList.add('start');
  setTimeout(function() { document.body.classList.add('transitioned'); }, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear exactly what you're trying to do with your specific code, but the general answer for stopping a timer is that you save the result from `setTimeout()` into a variable that is in a high enough scope or on a property of an object that you can later access it and then use it to call `clearTimeout()`.  That will stop the timer.

In your current code, the variable `clock` is local only to the `timer()` function so as soon as that function finishes, it will be out of scope and unreachable.  You likely need to move the `clock` variable to a higher scope where it will be accessible from whatever code you want to stop the timer from.

---

Or, if the issue you're asking about is how to tell your `add()` function to stop issuing new `timer()` calls when it has reached a certain position, then you can just add an `if()` statement to your `add()` function and not call `timer()` again if some condition has been met.

For example:

```
function add() {
    window.scrollTo(0, positionYTop += speed);
    if (window.scrollTop < 400) {
        timer();
    }
}
```

Comment: my be you can help,or corret me whit the code litle bit...?

Comment: Thank you, but your suggestions are to rewrite the code..? but it's not smooth scrolling now (((

Comment: @GuntarWi - I showed a code example of how to change `add()` so that it stops making a new timer when the scroll position reaches a certain position.  That appears to be what your question was asking.

Comment: Oooo now i have onother problem how to make the scroll smooth (((

Comment: @GuntarWi - First search the web for scroll animation or smooth scroll.  Then, try something you find there.  Then, if you get stuck, post a new question, showing what code you tried.