# How to stop a timeout if it is running in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a timeout setup like this below:

```
var someObj = {

  init: function() {

    someObj.timeout();
    someObj.someWork();

  },

  timeout : setTimeout(function() {
        someObj.myFunc();
    }, 15000),

  myFunc: function() {
        console.log('myFunction called');
    },

  someWork: function(){
    console.log('some work');
    if(this.timeout !== null){
        console.log('clearing timeout...');
        clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    }
  }

}

$(function() {
    someObj.init();
});
```

I want to stop the timeout if it is assigned to `timeout` variable and not null.

Jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/jy2p7jtd/17/

Is it possible?

**Update:**

Is this valid way to assign a timeout and clear it?

```
var someObj = {

 timeout :null,

  init: function() {
    someObj.make();
    someObj.someWork();
  },

  make: function(){
    this.timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('myFunction called');
    }, 15000)
  },

  someWork: function(){
    console.log('timeout is ', this.timeout);
    if(this.timeout !== null){
        console.log('clearing timeout...');
        clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    }
  }
}

$(function() {
    someObj.init();
});
```

updated link: https://jsfiddle.net/jy2p7jtd/41/

Comment: Have you even googled?

Comment: Use clearTimeout()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript how to stop setTimeOut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34845844/javascript-how-to-stop-settimeout)

Comment: It is a duplicate of existing question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34845844/javascript-how-to-stop-settimeout

Comment: Actually if you guys read the question carefully, it's not just asking for the `clearTimeout` method... It's even already in the code that he posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

declare another property `timeoutId:null` and check if it is present then clear it.

```js
var someObj = {
  timeoutId: null,
  init: function() {
    this.timeoutId = this.timeout();
    someObj.someWork();
  },

  timeout: function() {
    return setTimeout(function() {
      someObj.myFunc();
    }, 15000)
  },

  myFunc: function() {
    console.log('myFunction called');
  },

  someWork: function() {
    console.log('some work');
    if (this.timeoutId) {
      console.log('clearing timeout...');
      clearTimeout(this.timeoutId);
    }
  }

}

$(function() {
  someObj.init();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Durga Updated my question. Is that a valid way to assign and clear a timeout? Could you please check

Comment: @Satyadev Here is update [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jy2p7jtd/43/), After clearing timeout you assign that id to null.

Answer (score 0):

`clearTimeout()` prevents the function set with the setTimeout() to execute.